# Aggregate and compress CSS/JS not working with Amazon S3

Tags: 7

I am using [Amazon S3](https://www.drupal.org/project/amazons3), [S3fs](https://www.drupal.org/project/s3fs) modules, I cant able to Aggregate and compress CSS/JS in Performance(`admin/config/development/performance`), as it is disabled.

[image]
And it says "Set up the public files directory to make these optimizations available".

I need to use `Amazon Single Storage Service` in performance

[image]

Any suggestions how to compress js/css.